# AngularJS/PHP/Javascript - Não consigo atualizar o valor do ng-model

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, sql-update

Primeiramente boa noite. Tenho uma tabela simples que é alimentada por um banco de dados SQL. Desenvolvi um botão que possui o objetivo de atualizar o conteúdo dos "ng-model" conforme o que você digitar em um form simples. A tabela é atualizada através de uma requisição http.post.
O problema é que os "ng-model" não estão atualizando após a gravação, mantendo assim os valores antigos.  Gente, acredito que seja algum deslize simples meu com relação a passagem de parâmetros.... podem me dar uma força?

```
<!-- BUTTON EDITAR -->

        <button ng-class="['uk-button', 'uk-button-primary', 'uk-button-small']" href="#modal-editar{{x.id}}" ng-click="updateRegister(x.id,x.cliente,x.descricao,x.valor,x.dataM,x.tipo)" uk-toggle>Update</button>

        <!-- INICIO MODAL EDITAR -->

        <div id="modal-editar{{x.id}}" uk-modal>
        <!-- BOTÃO DE FECHAR -->
            <div ng-class="['uk-modal-dialog']">
                <button ng-class="['uk-modal-close-default']" type="button" uk-close></button>
            <div ng-class="['uk-modal-header']">
            <!-- TITULO DA ENTRADA -->
                <h2 ng-class="['uk-modal-title']">{{x.titulo}}</h2>
            </div>

            <div ng-class="['uk-modal-body']">
                <label ng-class="['formulario']">Cliente</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="ngCliente" ng-class="['uk-input','uk-form-width-medium','uk-form-small']"></input>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="['uk-modal-body']">
                <label ng-class="['formulario']">Descricao</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="ngDescricao" ng-class="['uk-input','uk-form-width-medium','uk-form-small']"></input>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="['uk-modal-body']">
                <label ng-class="['formulario']">Valor</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="ngValor" ng-class="['uk-input','uk-form-width-medium','uk-form-small']"></input>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="['uk-modal-body']">
                <label ng-class="['formulario']">Data</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="ngDataM" ng-class="['uk-input','uk-form-width-medium','uk-form-small']"></input>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="['uk-modal-body']">
                <label ng-class="['formulario']">Tipo</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="ngTipo" ng-class="['uk-input','uk-form-width-medium','uk-form-small']"></input>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="['uk-modal-footer uk-text-right']">
                <button ng-class="['uk-button uk-button-primary uk-modal-close']" ng-click="updateRegisterIntoDB(x.id)" type="button">Salvar</button>
                <button ng-class="['uk-button uk-button-secondary uk-modal-close']" type="button">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
```

PHP

```
include("../sqlConnection/connection.php");

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if(count($data)>0)
{

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $data->value);
$cliente = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $data->cliente);
$descricao = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $data->descricao);
$valor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $data->valor);
$dataM = substr("$data->dataM",0,10);
$tipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $data->tipo);

$query = "UPDATE listafinanceira SET cliente='$cliente',descricao='$descricao',valor='$valor',dataM='$dataM',tipo='$tipo' WHERE id = '$id'";
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$scope.updateRegister = function(cliente,descricao,valor,dataM,tipo)
{ 
        $scope.ngCliente = cliente;
        $scope.ngDescricao = descricao;
        $scope.ngValor = valor;      
        $scope.ngDataM = dataM;    
        $scope.ngTipo = tipo;  
}

//objeto responsável por atualizar o formulario com os dados preenchidos dentro do modal
$scope.updateRegisterIntoDB = function(value)
{

        $http.post(
                "../sqlFunctions/updateForm.php",
                {value:value,cliente:$scope.ngCliente,descricao:$scope.ngDescricao,valor:$scope.ngValor,dataM:$scope.ngDataM,tipo:$scope.ngTipo}
            ).then(function(data){
                alert("Cadastro atualizado com sucesso"); 
                $scope.entradas = data;
                $scope.displayData();
            });
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você está utilizando o *ng-repeat* para gerar o seu *grid* certo? Se realmente for isso, tenha certeza de além de atualizar a sua base de dados você também atualize o seu *array* responsável de dados.
Caso a linha responsável por atualizar os dados seja:

```
$scope.entradas = data;
```

lembre-se que a sintaxe para capturar o corpo do retorno será:

```
$scope.entradas = data.data;
```

Comment: Já resolvi jovem, era coisa simples. Mas agradeço sua resposta!